# Windows Phone xaml markup

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, markup

Is there XAML solution for this sample? I'm interested in part where fullname and little dot are shown. Particularly, I can't make little dot to be right after fullname if fullname has enough space (first item).

Now, I have this, but it's not appropriate because the dot is always on the right:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="0,-16,0,0"
            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Text="{Binding Path=IsOnline, Converter={StaticResource StatusFormatter}}" Opacity="0.6"
            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: To avoid downvotes, post [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far.

Comment: If you add a spacer ColumnDefinition, it should work. I can't test it so I won't post it as an answer, but the syntax would be : <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>, and make your text in Column 0 and your 'dot' in Column 2

Comment: Doesn't work. The dot disappears if fullname is too long

Comment: Do you want the dot to always appear? if so, where do you want the dot?

Comment: The dot is for _online status_. The dot must be right after the fullname if it has enoght space to fit screen (john Doe), but if the fullname is too long, the dot must be right aligned (Benjamin Washington)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this question by writing Custom Panel:

```
public class MyStackPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size newSize = new Size();
        UIElement firstChild = Children[0];
        UIElement secondChild = Children[1];
        secondChild.Measure(availableSize);
        firstChild.Measure(new Size(availableSize.Width - secondChild.DesiredSize.Width, availableSize.Height));
        newSize.Width = firstChild.DesiredSize.Width + secondChild.DesiredSize.Width;
        newSize.Height = firstChild.DesiredSize.Height;
        return newSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        UIElement firstChild = Children[0];
        UIElement secondChild = Children[1];
        firstChild.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, firstChild.DesiredSize.Width, firstChild.DesiredSize.Height));
        secondChild.Arrange(new Rect(firstChild.DesiredSize.Width, 0, secondChild.DesiredSize.Width,
                                     firstChild.DesiredSize.Height));
        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<local:MyStackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsOnline, Converter={StaticResource StatusFormatter}}"
               Opacity="0.6"
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
</local:MyStackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach: bind TextBlock MaxWidth to Widtd of the Grid minus width of the dot(for example 10 pixels). There are two variants: use converter or element binding.
Here is how to do this using element binding:

First we need to create element with desired width:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/> 
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
    <Border x:Name="TextMaxWidth"/> <!-- this ActualWidth will be equals Grid.Width - 10 -->
</Grid>
```

then bind MaxWidth of the TextBlock to the border `ActualWidth`

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
    <!-- note that columns widths are changed; also you can use stack panel instead of grid -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>  
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>  
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
        <!-- this will restrict texblock from growing more than Grid.Width - 10 -->
        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=TextMaxWidth}"
        Margin="0,-16,0,0"  
        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />  
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  
        Text="{Binding Path=IsOnline, Converter={StaticResource StatusFormatter}}" Opacity="0.6"  
        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>  
</Grid>
```

Also you can bind TextBlock MaxWidth directly to the grid ActualWidth using converter with subtracts width of the dot.

Offtop: i thought that VK contest already over?:)

Comment: Yes, Contest's over, but i want to finish this stuff.

Comment: Why border disappeared from your second code-sample and columns definitions are different?

Comment: @Buddy second code-sample is a continuation for first code, you should use it all together

Comment: in second part you can replace grid with StackPanel `Orientation="Horizontal"`